# Attempted to call an undefined method named "flush"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, entity, entitymanager

I use:  `composer require annotations`  and then
 public function editAction(Product $product){

```
//        echo '<pre>';
//        print_r($product);

        if(!$product){
            throw $this->createNotFoundException("No product found for id:".$product->getId());
        }
        $product->setName('New product name!');
        $product->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('product_show',[
            'id'=>$product->getId()
            ]);

    }
```

$product object contains all property inside Entity but flush() method is treated as undefined. Here is the error message:

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "flush" of class "App\Entity\Product".
```

I solved this as follows:

```
/**
 * @Route("/product/edit/{id}")
 */
public function updateAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $product = $em->getRepository(Product::class)->find($id);

    if (!$product) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No product found for id '.$id
        );
    }

    $product->setName('New product name!');
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('product_show', [
        'id' => $product->getId()
    ]);
}
```

But I wanna do it with less code as I can pass $product object. Why the first approach is failed?

N.B: I am using symfony4.

Comment: why you using $product->flush() instead of $em->flush();

Comment: @abdussattarbhuiyan, Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: strange! why down vote,guy?. I thought my journey with symfony  will be enjoyable with the guideline from this community.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the manager, and call the flush on it, and not call `flush()` directly to the entity object

Like:

```
$em = $this-getDoctrine()->getManager();
$product = new Product();
$product->setName('New product name!');
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

Under line `$product->setName('New product name!');` follow this code:

```
$em->persist($product);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: I think he wants an `UPDATE` not an `INSERT`.